# Getting a Cannot read property of 'roles' even though code is working?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So ive been getting a error of (node:2256) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of null even though the code is working.

And this is my code:

```
if(message.member.roles.cache.has(muterole.id)){
await message.delete()
var logs = bot.channels.cache.get('754186242513698827')
const Embed = new MessageEmbed()
.setAuthor('Checked user roles with muted roles', message.author.displayAvatarURL())
.addFields(
{ name: `Found user with muted role`, value: `Sent message and automatically deleted.`, inline: true},
)
.setColor('GREEN')
logs.send(Embed)
} else {

}
```

Comment: Are you inside the `message` event?

Comment: Yes i am in the message event

Comment: It's working on my side, what version of Discord are you running?

Comment: Im using discord v12

Comment: @RedRideGaming What happens if you do `console.log(message.member.roles)` also it's `null` which probably means the user doesn't have any roles.

Comment: Roles return as     _roles: [ '754187358940823642', '754187201994031164' ],

Comment: Fixed: Added 
    if(message.channel.type == 'dm' ) return
    if(!message.guild) return
    if(message.author.bot) return
and no more errors.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: Added if(message.channel.type == 'dm' ) return if(!message.guild) return if(message.author.bot) return and no more errors.